# how to extract the text after certain tags using jsoup

Tags: java, twitter, jsoup

i am using jsoup to extract tweeter text. so the html structure is

```
 <p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">@sexyazzjas There is so much love in the air, Jasmine! Thanks for the shout out. <a href="/search?q=%23ATTLove&amp;src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" ><s>#</s><b>ATTLove</b></a></p>
```

what i want to get is`There is so much love in the air, Jasmine! Thanks for the shout out.`
and i want to extract all the tweeter text in the entire page. 
I am new to java. the code has bugs. please help me thank you

below is my code:

```
    package htmlparser;
    import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class tweettxt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc;
        try {

            // need http protocol
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://twitter.com/ATT/").get();

            // get page title
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title);

            Elements links = doc.select("p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text"");
            for (Element link : links) {


                System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("p"));
                System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

            }






        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't do it using JSoup, because the HTML structure of the Twitter website could change. You should use the Twitter API instead.

Comment: do you have the link for that api?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do agree with Robin Green about using the API and not Jsoup in this occasion, I will provide a working solution for what you asked just to close this topic and for help on future viewers that have a problem with

1. selector with tag that has two or more classes
2. Get the direct text of a  Jsoup element that contains other elements.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Document doc;
       try {

           // need http protocol
           doc = Jsoup.connect("https://twitter.com/ATT/").get();

           // get page title
           String title = doc.title();
           System.out.println("title : " + title);

           //select this <p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text"></p>
           Elements links = doc.select("p.js-tweet-text.tweet-text");  

           for (Element link : links) {
               System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("p"));
                /*use ownText() instead of text() in order to grab the direct text of 
                <p> and not the text that belongs to <p>'s children*/
               System.out.println("text : " + link.ownText());
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```